# Return JSON object with TypeScript function

Tags: javascript, json, function, typescript, return

I discovered TypeScript recently and I try to convert my existing JavaScript code to TypeScript.

I have a function that retrieves information from a string (`data`), puts it in a JSON object (`json`) and returns it. But when using TypeScript and not specifying a return type, I get the following error in Eclipse:

> No best common type exists among return expressions

It disappears when I add `any` return type, but I think this isn't a good solution (too generic). And I couldn't find a "json" or "object" type.

**My question is**: what return type should I use?

Here is the function:

```
function formaterDonnees(data: string) { // or (data: string): any
    // final json object
    var json = {
        y: {
            "vars": [],
            "smps": [],
            "data": []
        }
    };

    // ...
    // processing data...
    // ...

    // put new variables in JSON (not real values below)
    json.y.data = ["data"];
    json.y.smps = ["smps"];
    json.y.vars = ["vars"];

    return json;

};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can indeed specify that you return `object` ([new to typescript 2.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#object-type)), but you can create a type for your return value:

```
type MyReturnTypeItem = {
    vars: string[];
    smps: string[];
    data: string[];
}

type MyReturnType = {
    [name: string]: MyReturnTypeItem;
}

function formaterDonnees(data: string): MyReturnType {
    var json = {
        y: {
            "vars": [],
            "smps": [],
            "data": []
        }
    };

    // put new variables in JSON (not real values below)
    json.y.data = ["data"];
    json.y.smps = ["smps"];
    json.y.vars = ["vars"];

    return json;

};
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20MyReturnTypeItem%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20vars%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20smps%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MyReturnType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20MyReturnTypeItem%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20formaterDonnees(data%3A%20string)%3A%20MyReturnType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20json%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20y%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22vars%22%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22smps%22%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22data%22%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20put%20new%20variables%20in%20JSON%20(not%20real%20values%20below)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20json.y.data%20%3D%20%5B%22data%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20json.y.smps%20%3D%20%5B%22smps%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20json.y.vars%20%3D%20%5B%22vars%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20json%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%3B))

Also, while I used [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) you can do the same with [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

```
interface MyReturnTypeItem {
    vars: string[];
    smps: string[];
    data: string[];
}

interface MyReturnType {
    [name: string]: MyReturnTypeItem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I needed. Could you please explain me briefly the following syntax: `[name: string]:` ?

Comment: That's called [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types). I think that the documentation is pretty straight forward, so check it out, if you still don't understand something then reply again and I'll be happy to help

Comment: Typescript gives me an error when function return JSON in the response and at the same time specify the **object** type for the function return.